# STS Tomcat Deploy causes IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I am working with the following stack, spring framework, Tomcat 7.0 and maven and in attempt to compile and 'run on server', i cant seem to access the localhost address. I receive from the browser `404 /Dugsi_Manager` is not available.

- The first attempt was to switch this project to a maven project and try the 'update maven configuration'. (No go in fact this makes things worse as my stack trace shows several Bean definitions missing.)
- Second attempt was to remove all the tomcat instances and create new instances and making sure the deployment assembly had all my .M2 Repo jars included. No go.

Stack trace as of now.

```
    Sep 15, 2012 10:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
Sep 15, 2012 10:07:09 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Dugsi_Manager' did not find a matching property.
Sep 15, 2012 10:07:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 15, 2012 10:07:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 15, 2012 10:07:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1046 ms
Sep 15, 2012 10:07:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 15, 2012 10:07:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
Sep 15, 2012 10:07:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /Users/warz07/Documents/workspace-sts-2.8.0.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Dugsi_Manager does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4814)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
Sep 15, 2012 10:07:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Sep 15, 2012 10:07:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Sep 15, 2012 10:07:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Dugsi_Manager] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 15, 2012 10:07:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 15, 2012 10:07:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 15, 2012 10:07:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 374 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First: You need to make sure that Eclipse compiles the files! -- You can check it: if there is a WAR file, then the compilation process seams to work.
- Second: Make sure that the depoyment process works: Clean the Server and Publish the Project, then start the Server

Comment: Eclipse is compiling, war file had to be regenerated and multiple cleans did nothing. I had to eventually remove my entire work space and re-download. STS 3.0.0

Comment: @Warz before you download a new STS, I would try to create a new workspace or only a new tomcat server (in eclipse) first -- this should be less work and may help.